# how to run intermediate file generated in Cool compiler like x86 assembly file

Tags: linux, assembly, compiler-construction

I am learning compilers. Also I am interested in building a compiler myself for insight.

So I am referring to Cool compiler(Classroom Object Oriented Language).

I have download the reference compiler for linux from [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs415/cool.html) .

Cool compiler offers various options [image: options displayed by cool in terminal]

I have compiled using --x86 and --asm which produce .s and .asm file. **IT IS GIVING ERROR IN QTSPIM .**

How to run these extensions on Linux directly .

**EXAMPLE**

```
class Main  {

main():Object 

{ (new IO).out_string("HELLO WORLD !\n") };

};
```

FIRST (.asm file - assembly output )

```
                        ;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
String..vtable:         ;; virtual function table for String
                        constant string6
                        constant String..new
                        constant Object.abort
                        constant Object.copy
                        constant Object.type_name
                        constant String.concat
                        constant String.length
                        constant String.substr
                        ;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Bool..new:              ;; constructor for Bool
                        mov fp <- sp
                        ;; stack room for temporaries: 1
                        li r2 <- 1
                        sub sp <- sp r2
                        push ra
                        li r0 <- 4
                        alloc r0 r0
                        ;; store class tag, object size and vtable pointer
                        li r2 <- 0
                        st r0[0] <- r2
                        li r2 <- 4
                        st r0[1] <- r2
                        la r2 <- Bool..vtable
                        st r0[2] <- r2
                        ;; initialize attributes
                        ;; self[3] holds field (raw content) (Int)
                        li r1 <- 0
                        st r0[3] <- r1
                        ;; self[3] (raw content) initializer -- none 
                        mov r1 <- r0
                        pop ra
                        li r2 <- 1
                        add sp <- sp r2
                        return
                        ;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

SECOND (.s file - x86-64 assembly output )

```
.globl String..vtable
String..vtable:         ## virtual function table for String
                        .quad string6
                        .quad String..new
                        .quad Object.abort
                        .quad Object.copy
                        .quad Object.type_name
                        .quad String.concat
                        .quad String.length
                        .quad String.substr
                        ## ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
.globl Bool..new
Bool..new:              ## constructor for Bool
                        pushq %rbp
                        movq %rsp, %rbp
                        ## stack room for temporaries: 1
                        movq $8, %r14
                        subq %r14, %rsp
                        ## return address handling
                        movq $4, %r12
                        movq $8, %rsi
            movq %r12, %rdi
            call calloc
            movq %rax, %r12
                        ## store class tag, object size and vtable pointer
                        movq $0, %r14
                        movq %r14, 0(%r12)
                        movq $4, %r14
                        movq %r14, 8(%r12)
                        movq $Bool..vtable, %r14
                        movq %r14, 16(%r12)
                        ## initialize attributes
                        ## self[3] holds field (raw content) (Int)
                        movq $0, %r13
                        movq %r13, 24(%r12)
                        ## self[3] (raw content) initializer -- none 
                        movq %r12, %r13
                        ## return address handling
                        movq %rbp, %rsp
                        popq %rbp
                        ret
                        ## ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: _"I have compiled using --x86 and --asm which produce .s and .asm file. IT IS GIVING ERROR IN QTSPIM"_  QtSpim is a MIPS simulator, not an x86 simulator. The code looks like something that would assemble with the GNU assembler.

Comment: @Michael - can u tell me how to run  this . i have paste the complete code .

Comment: i can paste  the complete code but so limits is 30,000 only ...

Comment: If you're on an x86-64 computer and OS, just assemble and link the code, then run it like you'd run any other command-line executable. I would expect the Cool documentation to specify how to assemble and link the output, so start by looking there. If you can't find it there, search for some x86-64 Linux assembly tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I figure this answer might help someone else starting out using Cool while following (some variation of) Alex Aiken's compilers course.

The thing is that multiple version of Professor Aiken's compilers course abound online, so if you're referring to material from one version (say, [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFB9EC7B8FE963EB8) YouTube videos) while using code designed for a different version (say [this one](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs415/cool.html)), you're liable to get confused.

What the OP is running is one of the Cool *interpreters* for x86 architectures (that can be downloaded from [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs415/cool.html)). Running `cool valid-cool-program.cl` is going to cause your program to be interpreted (run). This version *can* be made to spit out assembly by invoking it with the appropriate flag, but AFAIK only x86 assembly itself.

On the other hand, the YouTube playlist linked above refers to the use of a Cool *compiler* that compiles the source program and emits MIPS assembly, which can then be passed for execution to [spim](http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/), which is a MIPS simulator.

Probably the easiest way to run the latter version is to use a preconfigured Linux VM (provided [here](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/Compilers/Fall2014/9f961242edfb45eba0969a5a7592916d/)).

I only started going through the course yesterday, so if there are any more "incompatibilities" to be encountered, I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gcc` to assemble the `.s` files to executables.

`gcc hello.s -o hello`